# Cabal install package in local directory not reflecting while importing in file

Tags: haskell, cabal

I am currently self studying Haskell. I am just a beginner so I haven't yet had a need to use cabal or stack. But right now I need to test some of my code using QuickCheck.

From this link that I found https://github.com/haskell/cabal/blob/master/doc/cabal-commands.rst , I ran the command `cabal install --lib QuickCheck --package-env .`  and got the following output :

```
axiom@pop-os:~/Desktop/Haskell-Learning/Course/Homework 10$ cabal install --lib QuickCheck --package-env .
Resolving dependencies...
Up to date
```

In the same directory, I have a `.hs` file and in that when I tried to import `Test.QuickCheck` the linter gives an error as the package doesnt seem to be available for importing.

Then I ran `cabal repl --build-depends QuickCheck` and then in ghci I was able to import it. But still it was not importing in the code file.

Then when I just opened ghci by firing the command `ghci` , the following shows up, which suggests that there is a package environment here in this directory :

```
GHCi, version 8.10.7: [https://www.haskell.org/ghc/](https://www.haskell.org/ghc/)  :? for help
Loaded package environment from /home/axiom/Desktop/Haskell-Learning/Course/Homework 10/.ghc.environment.x86\_64-linux-8.10.7
Prelude> import Test.QuickCheck
Prelude Test.QuickCheck> :q
```

Even after above, that is, being able to import QuickCheck in GHCi, the import is still not working in the file.

After this, I tried the following :

```
axiom@pop-os:~/Desktop/Haskell-Learning/Course/Homework 10$ cabal install QuickCheck
Resolving dependencies...
Up to date
Warning:
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@ WARNING: Installation might not be completed as desired! @
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
The command "cabal install [TARGETS]" doesn't expose libraries.
* You might have wanted to add them as dependencies to your package. In this
case add "QuickCheck" to the build-depends field(s) of your package's .cabal
file.
* You might have wanted to add them to a GHC environment. In this case use
"cabal install --lib QuickCheck". The "--lib" flag is provisional: see
https://github.com/haskell/cabal/issues/6481 for more information.

axiom@pop-os:~/Desktop/Haskell-Learning/Course/Homework 10$ cabal install --lib QuickCheck
Resolving dependencies...
Up to date
```

The import still doesn't work.
Any help is appreciated !

Answer (score 0):

The method I ended up finding is the following :
Run the following in the directory where you have your haskell file where you want to import an external package :

```
cabal init
```

This will general a small number of files and such in that directory.
Add the name of the package that you want to use in the `.cabal file that was generated` . For example, I wanted to use QuickCheck so my `.cabal file` looks like this :

```
cabal-version:      2.4
name:               Homework10
version:            0.1.0.0
author:             Name Surname
maintainer:         name@email.com
extra-source-files: CHANGELOG.md

executable Homework10
    main-is:          Main.hs
    build-depends:    base ^>=4.14.3.0, QuickCheck
    hs-source-dirs:   app
    default-language: Haskell2010
```

Then in the same directory, run the following :

```
cabal build
```

Then when you try to import the package in your `.hs`, you should be able to do so.